# Dynamically create a new array where each item in the original array is duplicated the given number of times

Tags: c++, dynamic-arrays

I do not want you to do the whole function for me...I just need some tips.

For example if I have an array like: {1,2,3}...

It should end up looking like: {1,1,2,2,3,3}

EDIT: here is my function so far:

```
int ExpandArray(const int expanded[], const int arrayLength, const int duplicate, int* newSizePtr)
{
    int newLen = arrayLength * duplicate;

    int newArray[] = new newArray[newLen];
    return newArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the final result

```
int* ExpandArray(const int[], const int, const int, int*);

int main
{
     int arr[] = {1, 2, 3};
     int size;

     int * expanded = ExpandArray(arr, 3, 2, &size);

      cout << "{ ";
     for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
          cout << expanded[i] << " ";
      cout << "}" << endl;

      delete [] expanded;

     cout << endl;
}


int* ExpandArray(const int expanded[], const int arrayLength, const int duplicate, int* newSizePtr)
{
int newLen = arrayLength * duplicate;
*newSizePtr = newLen;
int *newArray = new int[newLen];

for (int i=0; i < newLen; i++) {
    newArray[i] = expanded[i/duplicate];
}




return newArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
void myFunction (int p[], int *q) {
    int pLen = sizeof(p)/sizeof(*p);
    int *q =  (int *) malloc(pLen * sizeof(int));

    for(int i = 0, j = 0; j < pLen; i += 2, j++) {
        q[i] =  p[j];
        q[i+1] = p[j]; 
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < pLen*2; i++) {
        cout << q[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

[Run live.](http://ideone.com/rJlVjR)

Comment: well i tried running the one in the "Run live" link in a new program just to see how it works but what is malloc for?

its not declared anywhere which does not let the program build.

Comment: To allocate memory dynamically we use `malloc`. Read more about [dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation).

Comment: alright but that does not fit the requirements of the assignment because of the way the function is set up.

Comment: i was able to do it though. check out my answer.

Comment: ah i see why that malloc thing does not work. its because its from C not C++.

although there is a way to use it in C++ i just used "new" instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are a little unclear. Does duplicate refer to the number of times a single item in the initial array should appear in the final array? I'll assume that's what you meant based on the code you have so far.

Since you know how many of each item from the initial array is supposed to be in the final array, what I would do is loop through each element in the initial array. Now within each loop for each element, add it n times (or duplicate times) to the final array. You can use a separate counter for the final array since it will need to increment multiple times in one loop.

Comment: hey there i appreciate the tips, i actually ended up solving my function.